# How do I change Firebase default project in Terminal

Tags: firebase, terminal, project, firebase-cli

I'm just starting out using Firebase & firebase cli tools and I'd like to change my default project in terminal. I've switched firebase accounts, but it's still trying to access a default project in my old account.

Anyone got help on this?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

To change the current active project:

```
firebase use <PROJECT_ID>
```

**Note:** If you get errors with deploying your project, make sure that the account you are using is properly authenticated for that project.

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

Comment: Isnt this just switching projects / environments.  But how do you set which is the default?